# is there an option for httpie that is equivalent to curl's --path-as-is option

Tags: curl, httpie

Is there an option for httpie that is equivalent to curl's --path-as-is? I want to send the GET request without some characters url encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPie 2.1.0 (released on 2020-04-18) introduced support for `--path-as-is`:

https://httpie.org/docs#path-as-is

https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst